# how to get sed remembered pattern producing expected output?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to have the substitution pattern extract the first letter of the first name (which is presumed to be upper case) and the entire last name, but disregarding any middle name'

For example:

**John Doe** should produce `JDoe`

**John Andrew Doe** should produce `JDoe` as well

I have tried the following and all I get back is exact what I input, `John Doe`:

```
echo 'John Doe ' | sed -E 's/\([A-Z]\){1}((a-z)+) ([A-Z][a-z]+)* \([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+\)/\1/g'
```

Comment: How do you make the difference between a middle name and a last name with several words? As an aside: Please remove these useless `{1}` quantifiers (each thing in a pattern occurs one time by default: `a{1} <=> a`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed` and extended regular expressions you can do:

```
$ echo "John Doe" | sed -r 's/^(\w).*\s(\w+)$/\u\1\u\2/'
JDoe
```

or place as many characters followed by a space in between `"John"` and `"Doe"` as you like and the result is the same:

```
$ echo "John Andres Doe" | sed -r 's/^(\w).*\s(\w+)$/\u\1\u\2/'
JDoe
```

Which basically:

- locates the first `\w` (word character) anchored at the beginning and collects the character in a `(...)` capture group;
- `.*\s` skips any number of characters followed by a space character;
- `\w+$` collects the final word in input;
- (*none makes any assumption about the case of the first character*)
- the replacement is `\u\1\u\2` where `\u` converts the first character to uppercase and `\1` and `\2` are back-references re-inserting what was captured in the capture groups.

For example:

```
$ echo "john james dan doe" | sed -r 's/^(\w).*\s(\w+)$/\u\1\u\2/'
JDoe
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 1):

I know you wanted the answer in `sed` or `regex`

here are my two solutions 1 in `regex` and the other one is in `awk`

Regex

```
/^([\w]).* ([\w]+)$/
```

demo on regex101 https://regex101.com/r/MafQy4/1

and the second one that is in `awk`

```
    $ echo "John Doe" | awk -F" " '{print substr($1,1,1) $NF}'
```

Result
         **JDoe**

```
    echo "John Alex Doe" | awk -F" " '{print substr($1,1,1) $NF}'
```

Result 
         **JDoe**

Answer (score 1):

Guessing from your question you would need a regex like this:

```
echo "James Tobi Bond" | sed -E 's/([A-Z])[a-z]+ *([A-Z][a-z]+?)* *([A-Z][a-z]+)/\1\3/'
```

https://regex101.com/r/dvH8op/2